# Create a "TearDrop" Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to create what we  call a "teardrop/icecream cone" chart in R.  The goal is to be able to compare actual and relative values across many factors at ones.  I drew a mock up of what we want it to look like:

[image: Concept Image]

However, having trouble connecting the two points (aka making the cone) with a line that varies in size.  Here is some demo code to illustrate what I have so far.

```
person = c("Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane") 
period = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017") 
metric = c("Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2")
value = round( runif(16, -0.005, 1.0049), 2)

tmp = data.frame(person, period, metric, value)       

ggplot(data = tmp, 
             aes_string(x = "person", 
                        y = value,
                        color = "person", 
                        fill= "person")) +
  geom_point(aes(size = period))+
  geom_line() + 
  scale_size_manual("Year", values=c(3, 6)) +
  facet_wrap(~metric, nrow=1, labeller = label_wrap_gen()) +
  labs(y = "Dummy Example",
       fill="person") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.key = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30"), 
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5, size=22),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust=1))
```

If you run it, you can see that the 2016 and 2017 data points are different, want to have a smooth transition between them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---- solution ----
Here is the solution that thanks to you all I was able to put together:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

person = c("Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane", "Bob", "Joe", "Sue", "Jane") 
period = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017") 
metric = c("Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric1", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2", "Metric2")
value = round( runif(16, -0.005, 1.0049), 2)

tmp = data.frame(person, period, metric, value)    
tmp$x <- as.numeric(tmp$person) * .25 # to use continuous x
tmp$r <- ifelse(as.numeric(tmp$HALF_YEAR)==1, .01, .04) #set radious based on period

#Create single line for each person/metric by Metric
{
  tmp2 <- cast(tmp, person+metric ~ period, value=value)
  tmp2$x <- as.numeric(tmp2$person) * .25 # to use continuous x
}


#create dataframe for polygons to fill the cones
{
  #Create Dummy section (to create dataframe)
  {
    tmp.c <- rep(tmp2[1, 1], 4)
    tmp.t <- rep(tmp2[1, 2], 4)
    tmp.x <- c(tmp2[1, 5]-.01, tmp2[1, 5]-.04, tmp2[1, 5]+.04, tmp2[1, 5]+.01)
    tmp.y <- c(tmp2[1, 3], tmp2[1, 4], tmp2[1, 4], tmp2[1, 3])
    tmp.P <- data.frame(tmp.c, tmp.t, tmp.x, tmp.y) 
  }

  for(i in seq_len(nrow(tmp2))) {
    if(as.numeric(tmp2[i, 3]) > as.numeric(tmp2[i,4])) {
      tmp.x <- c(tmp2[i, "x"]-.04, tmp2[i, "x"]-.01, tmp2[i, "x"]+.01, tmp2[i, "x"]+.04)
      tmp.y <- c(min(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), max(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), max(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), min(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]))
    }else{
      tmp.x <- c(tmp2[i, "x"]-.01, tmp2[i, "x"]-.04, tmp2[i, "x"]+.04, tmp2[i, "x"]+.01)
      tmp.y <- c(min(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), max(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), max(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]), min(tmp2[i, 3], tmp2[i, 4]))
    }

    tmp.c <- rep(tmp2[i, "person"], 4)
    tmp.t <- rep(tmp2[i, "metric"], 4)

    tmp.P <- rbind(tmp.P, data.frame(tmp.c, tmp.t, tmp.x, tmp.y))
  }

  names(tmp.P) <- c("person", "metric", "x", "y") 

  #remove earlier dummy frame
  tmp.P <- tail(tmp.P, -4)
}

#Create plot
ggplot(tmp) + 
  geom_circle(aes_string(x0='x', y0='value', r='r', fill='person', color = 'person')) +  
  geom_polygon(data=tmp.P, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=person, color = person)) +
  facet_wrap(~metric, nrow=1, labeller = label_wrap_gen()) +    
  labs(y = "Example", fill="person") +
  scale_fill_manual("person", values=colors) +
  scale_color_manual("person", values=colors) +
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.key = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30"), 
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5, size=22),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.25,1,.25), labels = levels(tmp$person))
```

And it works great -
[Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WchNU.png)

Only issue now is that depending on the values, the graph is squashed - but I can't remove cord_fixed because then the circles become crazy.

Here is an example of the data and what it looks like:

```
value = c(0.96, 0.96, 0.97, 0.99, 0.94, 0.96, 0.96, 0.98, 0.99, 0.95, 0.96, 0.99, 0.97, 0.91, 0.95, 0.97)
```

[Squashed Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9BiZ.png)

Any thoughts on a work around for that?

Comment: Are your teardrop charts in any way related to "violin" charts?

Comment: @lebelinoz I think they want to represent the transition between two values, rather than a distribution. [Similar to this](http://public.tableau.com/views/TeardropCharts/NewChart?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no&:display_count=y&:display_static_image=y&:bootstrapWhenNotified=true) I guess.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws ... that is what I am looking todo, except vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: For the problem with the 'squashed' plot, it's because in our 'hack' we made the x-axis continuous and not discrete. So, if the range on x is the same as on y, the plot will be more square. We did this by multiplying the four levels as.numeric() in person by 0.25 to get a range of 0-1. If we reduce this to scaling factor to 0.02 or so, we can reduce the range to 0.2-0.8, in line with the smaller range in your squashed example. Then, make sure to change breaks in last line to something like breaks = seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.2). That should work. +xlim(.1,.9) for padding if you need it.

Comment: Perfect ... I created a dynamic scaling factor to use to make sure it works.

scaling <- (max(value)-min(value))/4
tmp$x <- as.numeric(tmp2$person) * scaling # to use continuous x
tmp2$x <- as.numeric(tmp$person) * scaling # to use continuous x
tmp$r <- ifelse(as.numeric(tmp$period)==1, scaling/8, scaling/4) #set radious based on period

I of course had to change anywhere the old radius was refrenced, but I have tried it on lots of different data sets and it works.  Thank you @5ayat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but you could simply draw it with a combination of geom_circle() from the ggforce package and geom_segment(). You would have to clean up the legend for circle diameter, and maybe adjust some of the scaling values for better looking cones, but for example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

tmp$x.origin <- as.numeric(tmp$person) * .25 # to use continuous x
tmp$r <- abs(as.numeric(tmp$period) - 3) *.02 # vary radius by year
tmp2 <- cbind(tmp[1:8,],tmp[9:16,c(4,6)]) # messy reshape...
names(tmp2)[4:8] <- c("value.2016", "x.origin", "r.2016", "value.2017", "r.2017")

ggplot(tmp) + geom_circle(aes(x0=x.origin, y0=value, r=r, fill=person, color = person, alpha = .3)) + 
  geom_segment(data = tmp2, aes(x = x.origin - r.2016, xend = x.origin - r.2017, y = value.2016, yend = value.2017, color = person)) + 
  geom_segment(data = tmp2, aes(x = x.origin + r.2016, xend = x.origin + r.2017, y = value.2016, yend = value.2017, color = person)) + 
  facet_wrap(~metric, nrow=1, labeller = label_wrap_gen()) +    labs(y = "Dummy Example", fill="person") + coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.25,1,.25), labels = levels(tmp$person))
```

[image]

Comment: I have long given up on elegant!  This looks like it will be a great start for me  to work with.  Only question now ... any idea on how to fill the area between the segments?

Comment: Talking about not elegant ... I was able to take what you did, create polygons to fill it out.  Thanks @5ayat!

Comment: Should work to use geom_polygon instead of geom_segment to make tiny trapezoids with origin for both circles and radius offsets for 4 points of polygon, then can fill with ‘person’.

Comment: Thanks @5ayat ... I have it mostly working now, I just updated the question with the solution, but also show an additional question ... depending on the values the results get smashed together.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably create a teardrop chart, but what about one of these options?

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(tmp, aes(period, value, group=person, colour=person)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=tmp %>% group_by(person, metric) %>% arrange(period) %>% slice(1),
            aes(label=person), position=position_nudge(x=-0.2)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ metric) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(period, value, colour=metric, group=metric)) +
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ person, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is a more effective visualization. If you're looking at change over time, it make sense for time to be an axis.

Comment: Appreciate the ideas @epii10 ... and we do have some views like that to represent other change and data, but for this we really want to be able to do the other visualization.